# Portuguese accent on macbook air keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macbook-air, localization

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Macbook air with english keyboard. My UI is setup for portuguese but the portuguese accent is not working. Any known solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for ya:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en

You can define a "compose key" you need to press before the sequence that defines your special character ("composed character"). If you need ã, you press the "compose key" then ~ and then a. The result is ã.

Go to **Settings > Keyboard> Compose Key** and you define your preferred key as a "compose key".